# NextJS: Set custom header during client side rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to set a session token header for every rendering request sent to the server by Next.JS. The closest thing I have found so far from the docs is this: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers

However, the settings in the link above doesn't work for me because `next.config.js` is loaded on the server-side, but the session token can only be generated from the client-side.

So how can i set custom HTTP Headers for every render request from the client-side instead?

Answer (score -2):

You can do it in your _app.tsx

```
    App.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {
      ctx.res.setHeader("header", "value");
    }
```